# Complicated rails query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here.  The 'Master' is the complete list of all jobs.  Then I have three filters for the different `door_manufacturer`. Some tickets have a `parts_mfr` which I need to fetch if it is the same as the `manufacturing_location`. I'm fairly confused. Again, I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

```
session[:door_location] = params[:location] || session[:door_location] || 'MASTER' 


if session[:door_location] == 'MASTER'
  @tickets = Ticket.where(active: true,
                          complete_in_shop: false,
                          manufacturing_location: session[:factory]).
    order(calendar_date: :asc).order(:calendar_order).
    limit(90)
else

  tickets_door_location = Ticket.where(active: true, complete_in_shop: false, 
          manufacturing_location: session[:factory])
  tickets_parts_location = Ticket.where(active: true, complete_in_shop: false,
          parts_mfr: session[:door_location])
  @tickets = (tickets_door_location << tickets_parts_location).
          order(calendar_date: :asc).order(:calendar_order).
          limit(90)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this instead if you have the most up to date Active Record:

```
tickets = Ticket.where(active: true, complete_in_shop: false)
tickets = tickets.where(parts_mfr: session[:door_location]).or(tickets.where( 
          manufacturing_location: session[:factory]))
@tickets = tickets.order(calendar_date: :asc).order(:calendar_order).
          limit(90)
```

I'm on an older version of Rails, so I haven't had a chance to test this yet, but here are some more examples: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/test/cases/relation/or_test.rb